# Build time arguments for Android

Tags: android, build, arguments

I need to build various versions of the same project with little differences between them. I would like to pass a parameter at build time in order to specify which version on the project I want to build. Is this possible ? If so how, if not, is there any alternative to reach my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). There is a [plugin for android](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).